# Outputing classification probability from the Qiskit VQC

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, variational-quantum-algorithms

I am new to Qiskit. For the last few days, I have been trying to train my first VQC to do some classification task. Now the VQC is successfully running but it could only output a label whenever I ask it to predict something using the "predict()" method listed in:

https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms.VQC.html

However, I would like to have it output the probability of each class. In my case, I have two classes. So I am looking for an output like [p1,p2] where p1 and p2 are the probability of class 1 and 2.

The reason why I need this is that I would like to draw the ROC of the network. So this question might be related to another post:

[Plotting an ROC Curve with Qiskit's VQC](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29897/plotting-an-roc-curve-with-qiskits-vqc)

Thanks in advance.